# Printer being shared on two VLans

Tags: vlan

[image]

In order to connect the printer to 2 vlans at the switch I would need to trunk that port to the two vlans?

The image is the network that I am planning to build.

Comment: I've never seen printers which support VLAN tagging. Why does the printer need to be in every VLAN, and don't you use a printer server which is accessible from each network either by putting it in both networks or by routing the IP?

Comment: It is important to remember what VLANs are used for: Security Management Administration To name a few, I don't see any reason to put your printer in two separate VLANs.

Answer (score 2):

Getting a printer on 2 VLANs at the same time isn't practical.  Unless there is some limitation between the VLANs (i.e. ACL), your easiest option is to just put the printer on one VLAN, and then get the people in the neighboring VLAN to communicate with it through the router.

PfSense can certainly route between VLANs, so you shouldn't have any issues.